# PhantomJS Resource request error

Tags: javascript, .net, парсер, phantomjs

Один и тот же код отрабатывает локально (Mac, PhantomJS v2.0.0) и на виртуалке (Ubuntu, PhantomJS v1.9.0/1.9.8).
На боевом сервера ни в какую.
Взяли на месяцок VPS, малоли бан по IP.
Ан нет, так же не работает (Ubuntu, PhantomJS v1.9.8).
Включаю `debug` и наблюдаю такую картину:

> [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: 2 ( "Connection closed" )
>   URL: "путь до скрипта"

Если `путь до скрипта` прописать в браузер, то скрипт загружается.
Парсим, не отрицаю, но не совсем хочется раскрывать что и кого.

Скрипт имеет примерно такой путь:

> http://site.ru/script.axd?magic

Насколько могу предположить - это управление ресурсами в `ASP.NET`

На той стороне ребята защиты накрутили или я чего упупстил?
Есть какие то выходы/обходы?

*Предположительно, что что-то проверяет на той стороне, но локально же работает...*

**UPD1**
Открыл доступ к скриптам:

```
http://109.120.149.144/srv/exist/
```

Если запустить:

```
http://109.120.149.144/srv/exist/prices.php
```

то в свойстве `[command]` можно увидеть команду, что передается `phantom`.

Если данную команду запустить локально (см выше), то результат возвращается.
Не понятно каким образом, но пару раз отрабатывало на этом сервере, и можно было видеть результат. (файл `good.png`)

Comment: Вы должны бы приложить к вопросу хрустальный шар. Как нам догадаться, что именно в коде не работает, без кода?

Comment: Берите Wireshark, записывайте траффик для запроса из браузера и из PJS. Сравнивайте и пытайтесь угадать что из отличий приводит к проблемам.

Comment: @VladD, Хрустальный шар на третьей полки справа. Предположил, что вопрос возможно на поверхности, к примеру не работает с .net в отличным .lo домена... ну всякое может быть. Так же писал, что не сильно хочется оглашать что и кого. Прошу прощения.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, благодарю за наводку. Рассчитывал на что то попроще. Ну да ладно...

Comment: @borodatych я способа проще, увы, не знаю. Зато практически всегда можно понять в чем дело.

Comment: @borodatych script.axd?magic - это выдача js из ресурсов. там нет никакой магии. но могут быть проблемы из-за кривой прокси между клиентом и сайтом (magic зависит от настроек сжатия, например). в любом случае стоит проверить логи на серверной стороне (логи IIS и логи Event Viewer/Application) , чтобы понять в какой момент отваливается, и доходит ли вообще запрос до сервера.

Comment: @PashaPash, доступа к серверу нет, иначе вопросов не возникло. `magic` - передача двух параметров, где первое-статичный хеш(не меняется день ото дня), второй число...вдруг прояснит что то...   Возможно ребята на сервере ловят `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

Comment: @borodatych первый - имя сборки и ресурса, второй - timestamp. Может ребятам с той стороны не понравилось, что вы написала бота для их сайта, и они просто включили бан (например, по user agent). Парсить - да еще и таким кривым способом - нехорошо.

Comment: @PashaPash, обновил вопрос. И повторюсь - один и тот же запрос отрабатывает локально и на локальной виртуалке, но не работает на сервере. Ни чего не меняется кроме места..если можно так выразиться...